# How can i Convert (2020-02-21 06:07:21 +0000) to "21 Feb 2021 12:00 AM"?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents, nsdatepicker

I am using device time to get date components. this works fine for 12 hours formate but if user changes device time to 24 hours it shows wrong calculations. used the following method to convert but it always return nil.

```
            let dateAsString = "\(Date())"
            let df = DateFormatter()
            df.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"

            let date = df.date(from: dateAsString)
            df.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy h:mm a"

            let time12 = df.string(from: date!)
            print(time12)
```

Comment: Well, to start with `mm` is minutes

Comment: i dont get it, can you please explain?

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. You have current today's date but want to print last month 1st day date. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605816/first-and-last-day-of-the-current-month-in-swift/45188324

Comment: `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss zzz` is saying, "convert my date value to years-minutes-days hours:minutes:seconds timezone"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried below it works fine on both cases. with `AM` or `PM` or `24Format` and if you remove `a` in `formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a"` gives you 24 Format. Even I am using this in my code.

```
let someDate = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm a"
let someDateTime = formatter.string(from: someDate)
print(someDateTime)
```

Print:

```
21 Feb 2020 09:35 AM
```

Answer (score 2):

So, the core problem you're having is the fact that `yyyy-mm-dd` is using `mm` which is minutes and not using `MM` which is months.

So, if instead, you tried something like...

```
let dateAsString = "\(Date())"
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"

let date = df.date(from: dateAsString)
df.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy h:mm a"

let time12 = df.string(from: date!)
```

it would result in

```
21 Feb 2020 6:00 PM
```

Now, the problem is, you could simply do

```
let df = DateFormatter()    
df.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy h:mm a"
df.string(from: Date())
```

and get the same result.

Remember, `Date` does not, in of itself, have a concept of "format", beyond what its "debug" output provides, so you can't change a `Date`'s format, instead, you use a formatter to "represent" the value of the `Date` in some human readable form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let date : "2021-01-20T21:40:59.416Z"

func setDate(date: String) -> String {
   var interval: Double = 0
   let convertedDate = date.components(separatedBy: ":")

   for (index, part) in convertedDate.reversed().enumerated() {
       interval += (Double(part) ?? 0) * pow(Double(60), Double(index))
   }

   let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: interval)

   let formatter = Foundation.DateFormatter()
   formatter.dateFormat = "LLLL dd, HH:mm at"
   return formatter.string(from: date)}
```

This will return a date in this format
--> "January 21, 05:30 am"

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
let str = "2020-02-21 06:07:21 +0000"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss zzz"
if let date = formatter.date(from: str) {
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a"
    let formattedDate = formatter.string(from: date)
    print(formattedDate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Swift-this answer helped me***

[swift - how to convert date from am/pm to 24 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398852/swift-how-to-convert-date-from-am-pm-to-24-hour-format)

// posting my work here aswell.

1. i had device formate in 24H.
2. i needed in 12H.
3. so i just converted date object to required formate with this code snippet.
          
           `let df = DateFormatter()
           df.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy h:mm a"
           let time12 = df.string(from: Date())
           print(time12)`